# Testing iOS app with localhost HTTPS connection Not working

Tags: ios, xcode, tomcat, https

I've gone in circles this weekend on this and don't know where to go next.

Background: I'd like to test my iOS app against my local Tomcat server with HTTPS.  I've created my own CA root certificate and digital identity certificate, but I'm getting errors when I connect my app on physical iphone teathered via xcode to my Tomcat server on localhost.

The errors I'm getting are:
NSURLErrorDomain code: 18446744073709550416
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey: -9800

(screenshots from xcode):
[screencapture of error in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF4Do.png)

Setup:
1) I have a Tomcat server running on localhost (on my macbook).  I have xcode installed and I'm running an iOS app on the simulator; I also have my physical iphone tethered to my macbook.

My server.xml file is as follows:

2) I have a mirror of my tomcat server running on AWS with a signed key from ssls.com  Everything works great there.

3) Also, I can successfully connect between my app and my tomcat server on my localhost through HTTP without issue.

```
http://localhost:8080/thetest/thetest
```

4) I can connect with the simulator via https to my tomcat without issue.  (Previously I wasn't able to connect and I was getting similar errors as on my physical iphone device.)

```
https://localhost:8443/thetest/thetest
```

Certificates:
I followed these instructions to a tee.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2326/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014136

Testing:
A) I can execute commands via chrome and safari on my macbook and connect to my tomcat server without issue -- no warnings.

see here[secure on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2mEa.png)

B) I can connect with my iOS simulator and connect without issue.

> 2018-02-18 10:07:26.741348-0800 folie[13634:1105541] [MC] Lazy loading
>   NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
>
> 2018-02-18 10:07:26.742612-0800 folie[13634:1105541] [MC] Loaded
>   MobileCoreServices.framework
>
> 2018-02-18 10:07:30.068718-0800 folie[13634:1105541] [MC] System group
>   container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7C6DF662-D026-419F-BDEC-96C130628095/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>
> 2018-02-18 10:07:30.070359-0800 folie[13634:1105541] [MC] Reading from
>   private effective user settings.
>
> 2018-02-18 10:07:32.203212-0800 folie[13634:1105541] -[ViewController
>   SignUp:] - 107
>
> 2018-02-18 10:07:40.315781-0800 folie[13634:1106003] Data received
>   from SIGNUP button:
>   HelloTESTING...

C) When I run my test app on my physical IOS device, I get the following output:

> ```
> 2018-02-18 09:50:26.555890-0800 folie[5058:1225079] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
>
> 2018-02-18 09:50:26.558353-0800 folie[5058:1225079] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
>
> 2018-02-18 09:50:29.640089-0800 folie[5058:1225079] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path
> ```
>
> is
>   /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>
> ```
> 2018-02-18 09:50:29.642837-0800 folie[5058:1225079] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
>
> 2018-02-18 09:50:37.833201-0800 folie[5058:1225079] -[ViewController SignUp:] - 107
>
> 2018-02-18 09:50:42.444278-0800 folie[5058:1225149] [BoringSSL] Function nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed: line 387
> ```
>
> Handshake failed. Disconnecting the session
>
> ```
> 2018-02-18 09:50:42.446312-0800 folie[5058:1225149] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c0165b80]: 3:-9800 Err(-9800)
>
> 2018-02-18 09:50:42.451062-0800 folie[5058:1225149] TIC TCP Conn Failed [2:0x1c4165100]: 3:-9800 Err(-9800)
>
> 2018-02-18 09:50:42.455194-0800 folie[5058:1225149] TIC TCP Conn Failed [3:0x1c4165340]: 3:-9800 Err(-9800)
>
> 2018-02-18 09:50:42.455519-0800 folie[5058:1225149] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
> ```
>
> (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9800)
>
> ```
> 2018-02-18 09:50:42.455650-0800 folie[5058:1225149] Task <B07F6A46-BE52-4439-A300-AF4C905AAD35>.<1> HTTP load failed (error
> ```
>
> code: -1200 [3:-9800])
>
> ```
> 2018-02-18 09:50:42.456039-0800 folie[5058:1225223] Task <B07F6A46-BE52-4439-A300-AF4C905AAD35>.<1> finished with error - code:
> ```
>
> -1200

Certificates:
Both the iphone and simulator have the same root certificate installed

[sim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw9f9.png)

[physical iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtFFe.png)

D) The last test I ran was testing accessing the tomcat server from my physical device using the chrome and safari browsers after tethering my device and shutting off cell and wifi.  Safari didn't show a page, chrome displayed the following error: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

[chrome browser ON iphone physical device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuwDO.png)

Comment: Have you tried to use IP address of your pc instead of localhost? As address on your iPhone of course.

Comment: Are you just trying to test your server-side web application, or are you specifically trying to test a use-case where you are modifying the system's trust store?

Comment: Do you understand what `localhost` means? It's whatever computer/device the program/app is running on. In the simulator, localhost is your Mac. On a real iOS device, localhost is the iOS device.

Comment: I've tried the IP address yesterday, but didn't seem to change the result.  I can try again.

Comment: I'm trying to test my server-side web app along with my ios app for remote development (not relying on AWS server on the internet)

Comment: rmaddy your comment on localhost definition is fair; however, the way I understand it, my iOS app running on my physical iphone (tethered via xcode) believes it's running on the same machine xcode is running on. 
 referencing localhost in my ios app works on my physical iphone for all my other testing (HTTP), so why wouldn't it work for HTTPS?

Comment: @user9211159 If your server is on your Mac (or anywhere else) then when you run your app on your iOS device, you can not use `localhost` for either http or https.

Comment: @rmaddy what do you suggest if not localhost for my setup?  I feel like this must be a very common task, what do others use?  IP address?  I was avoiding it since I don't have a static IP at home.

Comment: A proper hostname is the standard solution. Avoid static IP or localhost.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use the specific hostname instead of localhost as @rmaddy suggested.

Steps:

1. edit the server.xml file:

```xml
<Connector SSLEnabled="true"
           clientAuth="false"
             keyalias="**therealhostname**"
         keystoreFile="conf/teststorespec.jks"
         keystorePass="changeit"
           maxThreads="150"
                 port="8443"
             protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               scheme="https"
               secure="true"
          sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

1. When creating the certificate: use the hostname as the name of the certificate and also the dns name.  refer to the name in the server.xml file.
2. edit the iOS app to point to the specific hostname (eg. https://hostname" instead of "localhost".

Comment: Note that the `keyalias` shouldn't be necessary: Tomcat will use the first certificate it finds in the keystore, and there is rarely a reason to have multiple certificates in a keystore for a simple site as described in this question.