# iOS app using simulator reports "The certificate for this server is invalid." error [-1202] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain

Tags: ios, swift, https

Trying to send http post request to the server using iPhone14 Simulator. Code fragments is as follows:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://localhost:8443/process_file"))
  request.httpMethod = "POST"
var body = Data()  // add body data here

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
{ data, response, error in
    
    // Check for errors
    if let error = error {
        completion(false, error)
        return
    }
    
    // Check for a successful response
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 
      (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
        completion(false, nil)
        return
    }
    
    // The request was successful
    completion(true, nil)
  }

   // Start the URLSession task
  task.resume()
```

I tested the server code using Dart client sending post request and it works. Requests using Postman also work. But Swift code generates following error. I tried changing the certificates without any success.

```
2023-03-18 16:22:32.467056-0400 MyApp[3511:81183] Connection 1: default TLS Trust 
   evaluation failed(-9807)
2023-03-18 16:22:32.467811-0400 MyApp[3511:81183] Connection 1: TLS Trust encountered 
   error 3:-9807
2023-03-18 16:22:32.468325-0400 MyApp[3511:81183] Connection 1: encountered 
   error(3:-9807)
2023-03-18 16:22:32.484207-0400 MyApp[3511:81183] Task <1C9997DB-4481-42FC-9698- 
   7C1CE90AF535>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1202 [3:-9807])
2023-03-18 16:22:32.524509-0400 MyApp[3511:81183] Task <1C9997DB-4481-42FC-9698- 
  7C1CE90AF535>.<1> finished with error [-1202] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain 
  Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to 
  a server that is pretending to be “localhost” which could put your confidential 
  information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to 
  connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=("<cert(0x7ff70501f200) s: localhost i: MY-CA>"), 
  NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, 
   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:8443/process_file, 
  NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:8443/process_file, 
  NSUnderlyingError=0x60000215d8f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 " 
  (null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, 
  kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x600001e35540>, 
 _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9807, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
 _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9807, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
     "<cert(0x7ff70501f200) s: localhost i: MY-CA>"
 )}}, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
     "LocalDataTask <1C9997DB-4481-42FC-9698-7C1CE90AF535>.<1>"
   ), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9807, 
  _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1C9997DB-4481-42FC-9698- 
  7C1CE90AF535>.<1>, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 
  0x600001e35540>, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. 
 You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “localhost” which could 
 put your confidential information at risk.}
 Error sending file to server: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might 
  be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “localhost” which could put your 
 confidential information at risk.
```

Using Xcode 14.2  on macOS 12.6.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing iOS app with localhost HTTPS connection Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855033/testing-ios-app-with-localhost-https-connection-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer Apple’s [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) and add exceptions for localhost

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Also remember to create separate Info.plist for dev and production environments. Or before uploading remove this exception.

Comment: added the following to info.plist  
<dict>
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Link below helped create info.plist file 
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-13-missing-info.plist/

Comment: I get a build error when adding an info.plist

Comment: This doesn't work in XCode 14.2.